# Firebase resize extension fails time to time on multiple images

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-extensions

I have the Firebase resize extension and it works correctly. only when multiple images are uploaded concurrently some of them fail to load after resizing. I get 404 on about 3/10 which is frustrating since we now have to track on the frontend when an image fails to load and delete it for the user to reupload it. Is there a solution to this or a workaround like maybe retry resize or something. The default behavior of the user is to select multiple files at a go and upload them and this cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I ended up with this solution

```
const url=`https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${firebaseConfig.storageBucket}/o/${encodeURIComponent(
          event.data.outputs[0].outputFilePath,
      )}?alt=media&token=${metadata[0].metadata.firebaseStorageDownloadTokens}`;
```

This is the only way I found to get a url similar and consistent to the one in firebase console. Similar to the one gotten from `getDownloadURL` on the client

The previous solutions had been getting `signedUrls`, failed to work for my use case as they expire after some period.
The other solution when posting this question was

```
const file = storage.bucket(firebaseConfig.storageBucket)
      .file(event.data.outputs[0].outputFilePath);

  const metadata = await file.getMetadata();
  const url = metadata[0].mediaLink;
```

This gave a url starting with `storage.googleapis` and sometimes a firebase similar url, only these image urls failed to load with a 404 error 3/10 times on the frontend.

This [article](https://www.sentinelstand.com/article/guide-to-firebase-storage-download-urls-tokens) has been a great help in fixing this url issues for a while and I got the solution there as well.

*Sidenote*:
Also I had thought the function was getting several multiple requests at a go and was unable to handle the requests so I scaled up the `minInstances` and the `memory` too.
This again was not the issue, and I have removed the minInstances and reduced the memory to `1Gib`

Comment: Do you still think this could be still related to the extension? Or could this an issue with timing on generating a signed url? The extension now has a `public` image option, if you are with public images and want to avoid generating authenticated urls.